# Reading an MD5 hash from the database to allow users to log in

Tags: php, md5

I have inserted a user into my database table through phpMyAdmin using the predefined MD5 function. (I know md5 is not secure and I should use bcrypt istead, but I don't need that type of security, my only purpose is not to store the passwords in plain text)

Now my problem is that whenever I try to log the user in, I can never read the hashed password back. This is my code:

The function that is testing for the username and password:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `_users` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    $user_id = get_user_id($username);
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password); // issue
    return (mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false; // possible issue
}
```

The logging processing code:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Username and/or password fields must not be left blank';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Username does not exist! Please register before logging in.';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account yet';
    } else {
        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Username/password incorrect';
        } else {
            echo 'ok' . '<br/>';
            //set user session
            //redirect user
        }
    }

    print_r($errors);
}
```

How can I read the stored MD5 password to allow my registered users access?

Comment: Why has this been down voted? I've searched and I was unable to find a duplicate. While there are many MD5 related questions, none of the suggested ones (when asking this) had a solution to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a php expert, but it seems to me that you're reading from the database before md5'ing the password, or, for that matter, sanitizing your inputs.

Shouldn't you do instead:

```
$username = sanitize($username);
$password = md5($password);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `_users` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
```

As a side note, your implementation doesn't seem very secure to me. Why don't you use a framework?

Comment: I am working on a project and I'm supposed to build this from scratch. I am not looking for security as for now, my only purpose is not to store passwords in plain text in my database. I haven't got to the registration part yet, so I've manually inserted a user into the database and hashed the password using the MD5 option next to the password field. My problem is that I cannot read this hashed password therefore cannot log in the only user I have

Comment: Which doesn't change the core of my answer (all answers point out that you're trying to read the plaintext password from the database, so your query as is will never return the user_id you're looking for)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In this case, I did not need to change anything in my code, just the order I was doing it, as you suggested. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `MD5` while querying to the database.

Change the query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `_users`
WHERE username = '$username'
AND password = MD5('$password')
```

OR

```
$password = md5($password);
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `_users`
WHERE username = '$username'
AND password = '$password'
```

Comment: this would probably force the db to scan every row to then hash the password and compare it.  probably better to store the hashed password in the db and change the query to use the hashed password.

Comment: @myte many db's filters in order of the query, so first it'll filter where all username="$username" and only then MD5, so this solution is probably good, upvote from me

Answer (score 1):

So, you create a query with plain password. As `password = '$password'"` supposes that `$password` is just a plain value, for example `123456`.
If you store user passwords in your database as hashed values (and I hope you do), you should first hash plain `$password` value and search in database for a **hashed** value:

```
$user_id = get_user_id($username);
$username = sanitize($username);
// here, we prepare our password hash
$password = md5($password); // issue
// next we search here:
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM `_users` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
// After that - you can check what results do you get.
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, I needed to change the order of how I was doing my code. Only after hashing the password BEFORE the query, this would return the expected result. Voted up